# generic C - what happens when I call "struct *s"?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, declaration

I'm taking CS 107 Stanford course, and in the lecture we have this simple stack struct

```
// stack.h
typedef struct {
  int *elems;
  int logicallen;
  int alloclen;
} stack;
```

he mentioned by doing

```
stack *s;
```

it should automatically reserve memory space for the struct.

However, I got a segmentation fault and I have to manually allocate memory by doing this:

```
stack *s = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
```

When I try to print s, it shows a 0

```
// this will cause segmentation fault
int main(){
  stack *s;
  printf("%d\n", s);
  StackNew(s); 
}
```

```
// this is fine
int main(){
  stack *s = malloc(sizeof(stack));
  printf("%d\n", s);
  StackNew(s); 
}
```

So what exactly does `stack *s;` do?

Comment: Nope.  The only space reserved is for the pointer `s`

Comment: It doesn't allocate the space for the whole `struct`, only a space for a pointer to this struct (and the pointer is uninitialized)

Comment: `stack *s = malloc(3*sizeof(int));` that looks wrong.

Comment: *by doing `stack *s;` it should automatically reserve memory space for the struct* Nope. That's perfectly false.

Comment: Is it possible you misunderstood the professor and he actually said that doing `stack s;` reserves memory space for the struct?

Comment: And you should be doing `stack s;`. There is no gain to allocating a 12-16 byte structure. You can allocate that on the stack and pass that around by value just fine

Comment: `stack *s;` <<-- dont assume C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> he mentioned by doing
>
> ```c
> stack *s;
> ```
>
> it should **automatically reserve memory space for the struct.**

No, it should never do that.

> So what exactly does `stack *s;` do?

What it does however is declare a pointer to a `stack`. Or, in other words, reserve memory space for *a pointer* to `stack`. That pointer is not initialized, meaning it points to some random **(*)** memory location. And attempting to dereference it will result in undefined behaviour, which means that anything can happen, including your code *seemingly* working. This explains your statement:

> When I try to print s, it shows a 0

It's good practice to almost always initialize your pointers to `NULL` prior using them. This way, you will avoid a hole category of problems.

And also, don't forget to free your allocated resources after you no longer need them.

---

**(*)** Generally, it points to wherever it was pointing to the last time it was used.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
stack *s;
```

is a declaration (definition) within the function main of an uninitialized pointer of the type `stack *`. So the value of the pointer is indeterminate. Neither object of the type `stack` is created.

To dereference the pointer it must point to a valid object. Otherwise dereferencing of an uninitialized pointer invokes undefined behavior.

Pay attention to that to output a pointer you have to use the conversion specifier `p` instead of `d`

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )s);
```